# How to select a specifc Availability Zone on AWS to get Restcomm working?

Tags: amazon-web-services, restcomm

I tried to install [Restcomm for VoIP Innovations on AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/library?ie=UTF8&region=us-east-1&keyPairName=RestComm&status=success&appActionToken=aZwzcc8kR4Rbp4hRysRaWQ6qhWgj3D&securityGroupId=sg-42fe6c25&subnetId=subnet-38a54a05&productId=1e59d01f-c1b5-495a-8777-003c4527860e&version=7%20GA&instanceType=m1.large&securityGroupName=Restcomm%20for%20VoIP%20Innovations-7%20GA-AutogenByAWSMP-&fromSubscribeLaunch=1&vpcId=vpc-c0a04ba4&appAction=LAUNCH_RESULTS#Restcomm%20for%20VoIP%20Innovations) using the default setup but it didn't work.

This is the error message:

> Your recent Restcomm for VoIP Innovations launch failed. Your requested instance type (m1.large) is not supported in your requested Availability Zone (us-east-1e). Please retry your request by not specifying an Availability Zone or choosing us-east-1a, us-east-1c, us-east-1b. (Service: AmazonEC2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: Unsupported; Request ID: 9654025e-42e7-402f-93f7-969d2eb04845)

I tried small/medium too, with no luck :(

Any clue on how to force it on 1a/B/C rather than 1e?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you launching into a VPC or EC2-Classic?

Comment: I'll go out on a limb and guess VPC... and you're choosing a subnet, when you try to set this up, aren't you... a subnet in us-east-1e, perhaps...

Comment: Thanks! Indeed I have a VPC with a subnet in us-east-1e but also subnets in us-east-1a, us-east-1c and us-east-1b. The AMI on https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B00FFHJ6SU/ref=srh_res_product_title?ie=UTF8&sr=0-2&qid=1416187993986 doesn't seems to provide a way to select something else than the region... I tried with removing the 1e subnet also with the same error...

Answer (score 3):

Sorry that you are having problems with using Restcomm on Amazon Cloud. When you purchase Restcomm, you are only presented with the default Region, which is US East (N. Virginia). Depending on the type of setup you use (One-click or custom) you should be able to configure the instance as needed. It is also possible to start the instance using the EC2 console by searching for the AMI in the Region mentioned above.

When you launch the instance, you will be able to configure the subnet and security groups that will allow you to successfully use Restcomm. Here is a screenshot showing you how to choose the appropriate subnet. If you are not familiar with Restcomm, I suggest you leave this as default so that you can concentrate on familiarizing yourself with the platform.

The screenshot shows the default settings.

[image]

Comment: Thanks this is what I needed. Now it launched and I just need to learn how to use Restcomm :)